# Segfault coredump occurs when I use CPPUNIT_ASSERT

Tags: c++, gcc, fedora, coredump, cppunit

I recently updated to fedora 30. When running a test now, my code will coredump on the CPPUNIT_ASSERT in the destrctor of the Message,

gcc version:

```
gcc (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Cppunit version:

```
Installed Packages
cppunit.x86_64                                                       1.14.0-7.fc30                                                        @fedora
```

backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ff037a363ff in free () from /lib64/libjemalloc.so.2

#1  0x000000000044ea37 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::deallocate (this=0x7ff02fefc000, __p=0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>)
at /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:128

#2  0x000000000044cc39 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate (__a=..., __p=0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>
, __n=70999306) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:470

#3  0x000000000043eb9f in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_destroy (this=0x7ff02fefc000, __siz
e=70999305) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:237

#4  0x000000000043df95 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose (this=0x7ff02fefc000) at /u
sr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:232

#5  0x000000000043b9a5 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string (this=0x7ff02fefc000, __
in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:658

#6  0x0000000000738397 in std::_Destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (__pointer=0x7ff02fefc0
00) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_construct.h:98

#7  0x00000000007359f9 in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*> (
__first=0x7ff02fefc000, __last=0x7ff02fefb460) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_construct.h:108

#8  0x00000000007326a2 in std::_Destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*> (__first=0x7ff02fefb5e0
, __last=0x7ff02fefb460) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_construct.h:137

#9  0x000000000072fb65 in std::_Destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_str
ing<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (__first=0x7ff02fefb5e0, __last=0x7ff02fefb460) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_constru
ct.h:206

#10 0x000000000075d72d in std::deque<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11
::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_M_destroy_data_aux (this=0x7fffdd38c658, __first="", __last=non-derefer
enceable iterator for std::deque) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/deque.tcc:864

#11 0x00007ff0384e52ed in CppUnit::Message::~Message() () from /lib64/libcppunit-1.14.so.0

#12 0x0000000000ed4ac8 in UT_MyTest::basic(this=0x7ff034b294b0, chunks=std::vector of lengt
h 1000, capacity 1024 = {...}, index=...) at /home/felix/git/master/src/core/UT_MyTest.cpp:708
```

Removing the CPPUNIT_ASSERT on line 708 enables the test to pass without issue - including it coredumps with this dump above. The values of __first and __last are "" - not sure if that will cause it to dump. I'm thinking my versioning is off, but I'm not sure. Has anyone any suggestions?

Edit:

The line it coredumps on for this particular test:

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT(correctHashes != 0);
```

This coredump happens in any test that use CPPUNIT_ASSERT

Comment: Thanks for the formatting KamilCuk, forgot about that.

Comment: There's likely a bug somewhere in your code. Just because your program crashes here doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere in the code that executed up to the point of the crash, but the bug didn't result in the immediate crash, but the code limped along until it finally died here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] gives you instructions for a [mre] that everyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce your problem. Until you do that there is insufficient information for anyone to tell you anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to cppunit 1.15 from the fc32 repo fixed the issue for me.